# Can I compost cat litter in a high temp tumbler?

Tags: compost

We're buying an isolated composting tumbler that can maintain a composting batch above 150 for several weeks. Can I use this to compost spent cat litter (including poo) and then use the compost on plants made for human consumption (berries, tomatoes, garlic,...)

I would use a litter made out of sawdust or something similar.

Comment: There are many different cat litter, so you need to check what is written in the pack (and possibly editing the answer, so that we can answer better).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I compost dog & cat faeces?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/2726/1916) and [Is spent cat litter an appropriate source of nitrogen for compost?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1275/1916)

Comment: Question is specific to high temp tumbler whereas previous questions refered to compost piles and other set ups that do not reach a high temp.

Answer (score 5):

Even commercial composting operations such as zoodoo separate the feces of herbivores from carnivores, and only process the former for sale as compost.

The problem is that no home composting system can guarantee that the correct temperatures will always be reached each time they're used.

If you're going to process the feces of a carnivore, they normally ask you to let it stand for a year, and not to use it for growing leaf and root vegetables.

http://www.the-compost-gardener.com/composting-pet-waste.html

Edit: [Mother Earth](http://www.motherearthnews.com/nature-and-environment/testing-compost-tumblers-zmaz03amzgoe?pageid=1) tested in 2003 a number of tumbling compost makers and found that they didn't make compost any faster, finishing the compost in 10 weeks.

Comment: Cat feces can spread stuff like toxoplasmosis. The urine can, too, but it's not as problematic as the feces, from what I read. Yeah, I'd reserve it for trees and ornamentals. Graham Chiu, do you have any thoughts on the litter itself, as opposed to the feces and urine? JDelage, do you know the ingredients? Will the manufacturer tell you the ingredients?

Comment: Commercial ops are subject to regulations...

Comment: @Shule I'd get a sawdust, straw, corn cob, or paper based litter. Plenty of reliable options for the litter itself.